# Multi-label classification implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, kaggle

So far I have used Keras Tensorflow to model image processing, NLP, time series prediction. Usually in case of having labels with multiple entries, so multiple categories the task was always to just predict to which class the sample belongs. So for example the list of possible classes was [car, human, airplane, flower, building]. So the final prediction was to which class the sample belongs - giving probabilities for each class. Usually in terms of a very confident prediction one class had a very high probability and the others very low.

Now I came across this Kaggle challenge: [Toxic Comment Classification Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge/overview) and in specific this [implementation](https://www.kaggle.com/jhoward/improved-lstm-baseline-glove-dropout). I thought that this is a multi-label classification problem, as one sample can belong to different classes. And indeed, when I check the final prediction:

[image: ex1]

I can see that the first sample prediction has a very high probability for both toxic and obscene. With my knowledge so far when I applied a standard model to predict a class I would have predicted the probability to which of this class the sample belongs. So either class 1 or 2 or .... so I would have had - in case of a confident prediciton - a high probability for class toxic and low for the others - or in case of unconfident prediciton - 0.4x for toxic, 0.4x for obscene and small probability for the rest.

Now I was suprised of how the implementation was done resp. I do not understand the following:
How is a multi-label classification done (in opposite to the "usual" model)?

When checking the code I see the following model:

```
inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix])(inp)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(x)
x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
x = Dense(50, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I understand that `x = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")` results from having to predict 6 classes. Same would be with my knowledge so far. However, why is then a probability resulting for a mulit-label classification? Where is the implementation difference between multi-label classification and just predicting one-label out of different choices?

Is it the simple difference of using binary crossentropy and not (sparse) categorical crossentropy along with 6 classes? So that tells that we have a binary problem for each of the classes and it handles these 6 classes separately, so giving a probability for each class that the sample belongs to this class and therefore it can have high probability to belonging to different classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loss function to be used is indeed the `binary_crossentropy` with a `sigmoid` activation.

The `categorical_crossentropy` is not suitable for multi-label problems, because in case of the multi-label problems, the labels are not mutually exclusive. Repeat the last sentence: the labels are not mutually exclusive.

This means that the presence of a label in the form `[1,0,1,0,0,0]` is correct. The `categorical_crossentropy` and `softmax` will always tend to favour one specific class, but this is not the case; just like you saw, a comment can be both toxic and obscene.

Now imagine photos with cats and dogs inside them. What happens if we have 2 dogs and 2 cats inside a photo? Is it a dog picture or a cat picture? It is actually a "both" picture! We definitely need a way to specify that multiple labels are pertained/related to a photo/label.

The rationale for using the binary_crossentropy and sigmoid for multi-label classification resides in the mathematical properties, in that each output needs to be treated as in independent [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution).

Therefore, the only correct solution is BCE + 'sigmoid'.

Comment: What would happen if certain labels are not independent of each other? (e.g label_1 is independent of everything but label_3 is more likely to ==1 when label_2 ==1) Can you still get away with using `binary_crossentropy`?

Comment: If the labels are not independent of each other, I would personally remove two labels and keep only one column  with : value 1 where both are present and value 0 where none are, that is provided that they are always present.

Comment: However, if they are not always independent, I would keep both columns and would try to gather as much dataset as possible so as the network to learn that it is possible to have only cats in a photo or only dogs, for instance, not necessarily both labels.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply! What if all of them are dependent in the case of ordinal encoding, e.g label_1 = [0,0,0,0], label_2 = [1,0,0,0] ... label_5 = [1,1,1,1]?

Comment: It should still work. Practically, you do not have cases such as [0,1,0,0], since you would have only [1,1,0,0]. It still works

Comment: Ordinal encoding in the case that you mentioned actually limits the possibilities of combinations in the GT label, but the usage of BCE + sigmoid is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, this is not a "classic" classification problem. For the classification problems you described in your text, softmax activation is commonly used to achieve the effect with high and low confidences which sum up to 1.

If you want to predict a binary problem, like for example "credit card fraud", you can choose between softmax activation in combination with 2 output neurons (fraud<-> non fraud) and a regression model with 1 output neuron. In the latter, the single neuron will output values in range [0,1] and a threshold is chosen, for example 0.5. All outputs <0.5 belong to class 0 and all >= 0.5 to class 1.

If you want to build a model which is able to predict multiple classes for one input, you should use the regression aproach (latter one) and a sigmoid activation function. This enables outputs like the one in your image.

To be honest, I am not sure if the "binary-crossentropy" is the correct loss for a problem like this.

Comment: what loss function would you personally recommend?

Comment: Just using sigmoid makes the difference? So this makes the implementation a multi-label classification implementation? When I have for example x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x) this does not make it a mulit-label classifcation, because still it is a binary problem with belonging to either class 0 or 1. So multi-label would be that it can belong to both classes, 0 AND 1. So sigmoid alone does not make it a multi-label classification implementation?

Comment: With x = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")(x) I could still have the implementation that it gives me the probability that the sample belongs to one out of the given classes, but not making it a multi-label classification giving me probabilities that the sample can belong to more than 1 class.